# Highlighting Matsci.org forum - community promotions

Tags: discussion

At the moment, I don't think there are community promotion ads for 2021.

I came across the https://matsci.org forum, which was started in 2020 and provides discussion for many software packages discussed here (e.g. LAMMPS, pymatgen, ASE, etc.).

I wonder if, until community promotion ads happen, there should be a Meta post with community promotion links / descriptions?

Comment: Just for some context on what is going on with Community Promotions this year: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360627/will-there-be-community-promotion-ads-in-2021-if-so-when

Comment: Since it seems like it will be quite awhile before they are posted this year, I like the idea of having a list.

Comment: @Tyberius and Geoff, community promotion ads aren't available for Beta sites to have. Only fully graduated sites like Chem.SE can have them!

Comment: We will probably have to make our own post in the interim, but Beta sites may start getting these ads as well. [The future of community promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads?cb=1): "Depending on the level of engagement we see, we'll then decide on whether to expand these to more sites, and potentially revise the current policy of only doing this on non-beta sites."

Comment: I took your suggestion and set up a [Community Promotion Board](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/mmse-community-promotion-board?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the site. Also, I added some rss feeds from matsci to the corresponding chatrooms.